# Get com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credentials but without having to go to a website

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

My service needs to log in my google drive account, for that I'm using the example https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

I have my credentials.json file and it works. But, in order to log in, I need to open a website, then log in, and then the log in process finishes.

But, since I need to deploy this on the cloud, I would like not to do that process, and use a token or something (maybe with an expiration date or whatever), that automatically log in.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Try looking up [access and refresh tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: ^^^^ this ^^^^^